# How can I make the redux devtools chrome extension default to State instead of Diff?

Tags: redux-devtools-extension

Every time I need to refresh the page for my React app, HMR doesn't pick up the changes I need, Redux devtools switches from the `State` view back to the default `Diff`.  It slows me down because I keep having to click `State` over and over.  I have never used the `Diff` page and would like it to default to `State` when the page loads.

Either editing the extension source directly or having an option to remember the last clicked tab would work for me.

Comment: https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/issues/511